# mysql Select from Select

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I have this query:

```
    SELECT DATE( a.created_at ) AS order_date, count( * ) as cnt_order
    FROM `sales_order_item` AS a
    WHERE MONTH( a.created_at ) = MONTH( now())-1
    GROUP BY order_date
```

which will return result something like this (snapshot only otherwise will return per 31 days):

```
order_date  cnt_order 
2012-08-29  580
2012-08-30  839
2012-08-31  1075
```

and my full query is selecting based on above selection:

```
SELECT order_date
    , MAX(cnt_order) AS highest_order
FROM (
        SELECT DATE (a.created_at) AS order_date
            , count(*) AS cnt_order
        FROM `sales_order_item` AS a
        WHERE MONTH(a.created_at) = MONTH(now()) - 1
        GROUP BY order_date
    ) AS tmax
```

But it result :

```
order_date  highest_order
2012-08-01  1075
```

Which has the date wrong and always pick the first row of date where it suppose 2012-08-31. Maybe this is a simple error that I dont know. So how to get the date right point to 2012-08-31? Any help would be great.

Comment: you have aggregated the result from subquery which results single value which in turn also is correct. why do you really want to achieve?\

Comment: To get the highest order count from that subquery, as you can see the max() get it right 1075 but why the date is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ordering the sub query result set; something like:

```
SELECT
    DATE (a.created_at) AS order_date,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt_order
FROM
    `sales_order_item` AS a
WHERE
    MONTH(a.created_at) = MONTH(now()) - 1
GROUP BY
    order_date
ORDER BY
    cnt_order DESC
```

Comment: This is my second time I complicated thing with sql query, yes it can be achieved with just as simple as above with addition ORDER BY cnt_order DESC LIMIT 1, so no more super query needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ORDER BY order_date DESC` in subquery.